# Cloning room key card by using NFC

Tags: nfc

I live in a youth hostel of an university and we access our rooms and labs by using a contactless key card. I want to clone my card to my phone.

Is it possible to copy when it is key protected? Can it be hacked?

Comment: It depends on the particular key fob system in use. Cheaper ones just use an ID number in each tag and are easy to copy. Secure ones use a challenge-response mechanism, like contactless payment cards, and are practically impossible to copy.

Comment: http://i58.tinypic.com/2hq5nbm.png seems like it when the card has been scanned. I remember that they are typing some numbers to configure the card. Can it be key protection? or Key protection is more complicated than it?